# Stehen Kunstwörter immer im Singular?

Tags: grammatical-number

Haben Kunstwörter eine Pluralform und falls ja, wird eine Pluralendung benutzt und falls ja, ist es für jedes Kunstwort dieselbe Endung?
Beispielsweise könnte man versuchen, aus "Kekulalu", welches ein ausgedachter Marken- und Produktname ist, eine beliebige Menge an diesen Produkten als "Kekulalus" bezeichnen. Ergibt das Sinn?
Die Frage kam mir auf, nachdem ich jemanden einen Soft-Drink-Namen im Plural habe benutzen hören. Dann blätterte ich durch meine Dudenbände, habe aber nichts zu Kunstwörtern speziell gefunden. Hätte jemand eine Quelle?

> Ich habe mir heute ein paar Kekulalus gekauft.

Comment: Geht es dir nur um Markennamen? Falls nein: an welche anderen Arten von Kunstwörtern denkst du noch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mal abgesehen davon dass die meisten Markennamen keine frei erfundenen Kunstwörter sind: Warum sollte man sie nicht im Plural verwenden?

> Auf dem Parkplatz stehen zwischen zwei **Fiats** zwei alte **Zündapps.**

---

Die meisten Markennamen sind keine frei erfundenen Kunstwörter, sondern meist Kofferwörter, Akronyme oder (wie im Fall von "Fanta") einfach nur verkürzte Wörter:

- Adidas = Adolf ("Adi") Dassler (Name des Firmengründers)
- Fanta = Fantasie
- Fiat = Fabbrica Italiana Automobili Torino (italienische Automobilfabrik Turin)
- Haribo = Hans Riegel, Bonn (Name und Wohnort des Firmengründers)
- Inbus = Innensechskant Bauer und Schaurte
- Lego = leg godt (spiele gut)
- Persil = Perborate und Silikate (Hauptbestandteile des Waschmittels)
- Sinalco = sine alcohol (ohne Alkohol)
- Varta = Vertrieb, Aufladung, Reparatur transportabler Akkumulatoren
- Zündapp = Zünder- und Apparatebaugesellschaft

Die einzigen Markennamen, die ich finden konnte, die wirklich nichts bedeuten, sind:

- AXA
- Kodak

Beide wurden gewählt, weil sie in allen Sprache leicht auszusprechen sind und auch überall gleich ausgesprochen werden.

Comment: Ich dachte, ich hätte das vorhin schon geschrieben, aber offenbar habe ich es nicht abgesandt, denn jetzt ist der Kommentar nicht hier: "Fiat" ist auch ein lateinisches Wort, was nicht ganz zufällig sein dürfte; Wikipedia verweist auf Kunstworte, die praktisch völlig frei erfunden wurde, unter anderem auf diverse Modellnamen neuerer Opel-Fahrzeuge.

Comment: Die Verwendung einer Mehrzahlform hängt wahrscheinlich auch davon ab, ob das Wort für sich allein als Bezeichnung für einen Gegenstand (oder eine Einheit) gebräuchlich ist und ob es zu einem üblichen Schema für die Mehrzahlbildung paßt. *Fiat* und *Zündapp* können ein Fahrzeug der entsprechenden Marke bezeichnen, *Fanta* ein Glas oder eine Flasche davon. Die anderen Beispiele werden eher nicht in diesem Sinne gebraucht. (also nicht z.B. ein Varta, zwei Vartas) Ein Beispiel für einen Markennamen, der zwar ein Exemplar bezeichnen kann, bei dem aber keine Mehrzahlbildung paßt, wäre *Snickers*.